# No Persistence provider for EntityManager named (New)

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, persistence

I am attempting to call persistence.xml to display some data from a database in the Netbeans IDE. I have looked and tried the different methods that previous users have proposed but I am still unable to solve the problem.

I have used this to call the persistence unit,

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TimeEven DataBasePU");
```

This is what is returned when I try to run the file,

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named TimeEven DataBasePU
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
at internal.assesment.TimeTableEventList.main(TimeTableEventList.java:110)
C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Timetable\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1051: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Timetable\nbproject\build-impl.xml:805: Java returned: 1
```

This is the line 805 which is where the error seems to stem from

```
<java classname="@{classname}" dir="${work.dir}" failonerror="${java.failonerror}" fork="true">
```

As said previously,

I have already added the provider under the Persistence unit name,

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

And I have made sure that the Persistence is unit is in the META-INF folder,

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Timetable\src\META-INF\persistence.xml
```

It is in the Class Path, so I am not sure where the error lies.

Edit 1. Yep, I copied and pasted from the xml code (I misspelled it in there too haha)

[Image of Persistence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IU6ut.png)

Edit 2.

[Image of Files and Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ds5c.png)

Edit 3.

[Source Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmuNi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the exception you posted is caused when there is no persistence unit which matches to name you passed on Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory.
In your case:

```
<persistence-unit name="TimeEven DataBasePU">
```

So, could you check your `persistence.xml` if you are sure that persistence unit's name is same as you wrote in the code?

Or, Posting your `persistence.xml` might be helpful to solve your problem.

EDIT 1:
Can you check your dependencies?

If you use maven(pom.xml), It must have:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! Yep I added a screen shot of my Persistence Unit.

Comment: Hello, thanks for taking the time to answer. I don't think I have anywhere to add the dependency. (I did not select Maven Java Application when creating the project.) Is it suppose to be tagged on to the persistence.xml in the file META-INF? I have added a screenshot of all the libraries I have. Best regards.

Comment: @ThoreRin , Could you post your source directory structure?
I think i reproduced the error when `persistence.xml` is in incorrect place.

Comment: That's awesome! I have just posted it, will it be sufficient?

Comment: Looks weird...directories you posted seem right.
Could you try **Clean and build project** or re-create project with same code?

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you, that works! Would you happen to know why it work by any chance haha? I honestly didn't even know theres such an option.

Comment: Most of IDEs cache the files they created when they use at the build time. The files must be changed when the configurations that affect them are changed as well. But sometimes, It doesn't change automatically by some reasons. So **Clean and build project** builds your project with removing the files and re-creating them.